# como implementar correctamente JS de Highcharts en proyecto MVC asp.net y sql server?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

estoy intentando implementar un grafico de lineas con Highcharts pero al momento da pasar los datos al parecer hay un error, quisiera saber donde me estoy equivocando, previamente pude graficar con exito con chart js, pero decidi cambiar por una cuestion de diseño.
tengo la sgte estructura

Controlador

```
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Linea()
    {
        DT_Reporte objDT_Reporte = new DT_Reporte();

        List<Linea> objLista = objDT_Reporte.RetornarLinea();

        return Json(objLista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

un clase para acceder a los datos de mi procedimiento almacenado

```
 public List<Linea> RetornarLinea()
    {
        List<Linea> objLista = new List<Linea>();

        //Data Source=;Initial Catalog= ; User ID= ; Password=
        using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=DBPRUEBAS2; Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string query = "SP_RetornarVentas123";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconexion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            oconexion.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    objLista.Add(new Linea()
                    {
                        mes = dr["fechaRegistro"].ToString(),
                        cantidad = int.Parse(dr["total"].ToString()),
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return objLista;
    }
```

Model

```
 public class Linea
{
    public string mes { get; set; }
    public int cantidad { get; set; }

}
```

en Index.cshtml, **segun yo mi error esta aqui, pero no se como arreglarlo**

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Linea", "Home")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                /*console.log(data);*/

                var arrayMeses = [];
                var arrayCantidad = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    /*console.log(data[i].producto)*/
                    arrayMeses.push(data[i].mes)
                    arrayCantidad.push(data[i].cantidad)
                }



            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: ' +
                        '<a href="https:" ' +
                        'target="_blank">Wikipedia.com</a>'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: arrayMeses
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        enableMouseTracking: false
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Marca',
                    data: arrayCantidad
                },]
            });
```

se supone que deberia reflejar el grafico en la parte que dice "no da tu grafico"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
<div id="container"></div>
<p class="highcharts-description">
    No da tu grafico
</p>
```

[image: este es el Proc Alm que uso para todos]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no se si aun sirve pero yo recuerdo que lo hacia de la siguiente manera, desde el controlador enviaba un ViewBag con un List con las fechas y otro con los valores a mostrar, nunca lo probé enviando un modelo pero me imagino que debe funcionar de la misma manera, luego esos ViewBag los recuperaba en la vista a través de un javascript una vez se cargaba la página, esto lo hacia parecido a esto:

```
var fechasArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.ListaFechas));
var cantidadArrayInt = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.ListaValoresInt));
```

y ya con esto es usar cada variable en sus respectivos lugares

Para el eje x mostraba las fechas

```
xAxis: {
    categories: fechasArray,
    crosshair: true,
    title: {
        text: 'Meses'
    }
},
```

Para el eje y mostraba los valores

```
series: [{
    name: 'Valores',
    data: ValoresArray
}],
```

Espero te sirva